# The method 'validate' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: validate()

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

No código criado no VS Code estou tentando implementar o validate ao receber a informação dos 02 campos de valores, por algum motivo o código está correto mais apresenta no DEBUG CONSOLE. Segue código do MAIN e PUBSPEC.

Meu código (main page)

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';
//import 'package:async/async.dart';
//import 'dart:core';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  ));
}
//acompanhar as alterações e atualizar a interface do usuário com base nessas alterações.
class Home extends StatefulWidget { 
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

//Interface do App
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final _toDoController = TextEditingController();
  final _toDoControllerN = TextEditingController();

  GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  //foi criada uma chave global

  String _infoText = "Lembre da última vez!";

  List _toDoList = [];

  Map<String, dynamic> _lastRemoved;
  int _lastRemovedPos;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _readData().then((data) {
      setState(() {
        _toDoList = json.decode(data);
        _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      });
    });
  }

  void _addToDo() {
    setState(() {
      Map<String, dynamic> newToDo = Map();
      newToDo["title"] = _toDoController.text +"  "+ _toDoControllerN.text;
      _toDoController.text = "";
      _toDoControllerN.text = "";
      newToDo["ok"] = false;
      _toDoList.add(newToDo);
      _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      _saveData();
    });
  }

  //recebe os dados após algum intervalo e representa um processamento assíncrono
  //pode ter êxito ou pode falhar e o código precisa lidar com ambos os casos) 
  Future<Null> _refresh() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    setState(() {
      _toDoList.sort((a, b) {
        if (a["ok"] && !b["ok"])
          return 1;
        else if (!a["ok"] && b["ok"])
          return -1;
        else
          return 0;
      });
      _saveData();
    });
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Lista de Compras"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        key: _formkey,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Expanded( //input respeite o tamanho da tela
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _toDoController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "  Descrição do Item :",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 22.0)),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Image.asset(
              "imagens/logo.jpg",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: 100.0,
            ),

          Container(
            child: Expanded(
              child:TextFormField(
                controller: _toDoControllerN,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "  Valor :",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 20.0)),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                validator: (value){
                  if (value.isEmpty){
                    print("vazio");
                    setState(() {
                      _infoText = "vazio";
                    });
                    return "vazio!";
                  }

                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
                RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  child: Text("ADD"),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: (){
                    print("ENTROU AQUI");
                      if(_formkey.currentState.validate()){
                        _addToDo();
                        print("ENTROU NO IFPI");

                    }
                  },

                ),

                Text(
                _infoText,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),  

          /////aqui

          Expanded(
            child: RefreshIndicator(
                onRefresh: _refresh,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                    itemCount: _toDoList.length,
                    itemBuilder: buildItem)),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildItem(context, index) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: Key(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()),
      background: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment(-0.9, 0.0),
          child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
      child: CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text(_toDoList[index]["title"]),
        value: _toDoList[index]["ok"],
        secondary: CircleAvatar(
          child: Icon(_toDoList[index]["ok"] ? Icons.check : Icons.error),
        ),
        onChanged: (c) {
          setState(() {
            _toDoList[index]["ok"] = c;
            _saveData();
          });
        },
      ),
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        setState(() {
          _lastRemoved = Map.from(_toDoList[index]);
          _lastRemovedPos = index;
          _toDoList.removeAt(index);
          _saveData();

          final snack = SnackBar(
            content: Text("Tarefa \"${_lastRemoved["title"]}\"removida!"),
            action: SnackBarAction(
              label: "Desfazer",
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _toDoList.insert(_lastRemovedPos, _lastRemoved);
                  _saveData();
                });
              },
            ),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
          );
          Scaffold.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snack);
        });
      },
    );
  }

  Future<File> _getFile() async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return File("${directory.path}/data.json");
  }

  Future<File> _saveData() async {
    String data = json.encode(_toDoList);
    final file = await _getFile();
    return file.writeAsString(data);
  }
}

Future<String> _readData() async {
  try {
    final file = await _getFile();
    return file.readAsString();
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}


_getFile() {}
```

---

Meus packages utilizados (Pubspec)

```
name: lista_tarefas
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  path_provider: ^1.1.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
  - imagens/logo.jpg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Experimenta usar um print pra mostrar os valores que estão sendo validados, pode ser que algum valor esteja nullo na hora de validar a informação dos campos.

Answer (score 3):

O que você precisa é utilizar um `Form`, segue um exemplo de como você pode fazer:

```
GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime _nextMaintenanceValue;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                validator: (value){ return value == "" ? "Obrigatório!" : null;},
                onSaved: (value) => dataObject.name = value,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                validator: (value){ return value == "" ? "Obrigatório!" : null;},
                onSaved: (value) => dataObject.description = value,
              ),
            ]
          ),
        )
    )
}

void onSave(BuildContext context) async {
    var form = _formKey.currentState;
    if(form.validate()){
      form.save();

      SalvarDados();
    }
}
```

Você está errando também em criar várias vezes a `GlobalKey<FormState>` deixando assim ela sempre com valores NULOS... Crie ela apenas uma vez e então vincule ela ao `Form`.

Você pode dar uma olhadinha também nesse [exemplo](https://github.com/matheusrmribeiro/EquipmentMaintenance/blob/master/lib/views/qrCodeGenerator.dart) que disponibilizei em meu GitHub.

*Para ver o [projeto completo](https://github.com/matheusrmribeiro/EquipmentMaintenance)*

Comment: Ainda persiste no DEBUG!

Comment: Você modificou sua classe conforme eu falei? Você está criando sua `GlobalKey<FormState>` três vezes... Instancie ela apenas uma vez, deixe apenas essa criação `GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  //foi criada uma chave global`